# Complexity of counting codeword length distribution

Tags: coding-theory

Suppose I have a code $C$ over $GF(2)$. I would like to count exactly the number of codewords of $C$ of weight $k$. Here $k$ should be thought of as small compared to the dimensions of the code.

What is the best algorithm for this? Even exponential algorithms could be useful.

Comment: Very closely related to this (unfortunately unanswered) question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19335/weight-enumerator-of-a-binary-linear-code

Comment: (a reference there mentions that for general $k$ it is #P-complete, http://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/66/57/82/PDF/BRIQUEL_IrA_nA_e_2011_ThA_se.pdf)

Comment: Note that it's NP-hard even to determine whether there are any codewords of weight $k$ [Vardy '97]. Therefore I suspect that essentially the best algorithm to solve OP's problem is the trivial $\Theta(n^k)$ one. Maybe some techniques from lattices would be useful to prove there's no subexponential algorithm under ETH.